# Clang and CMake on Windows - clang.exe broken, program not executable

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clang

I've set up Clang and CMake on Windows and when running cmake-gui on the OpenSceneGraph project source (configure step), the process fails with `Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/bin/clang.exe -- broken`.

Following the whole output:

```
The C compiler identification is unknown
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
Found Eclipse version 4.3 ()
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/bin/clang.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/bin/clang.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/bin/clang.exe" is not able to
  compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/OpenSceneGraph-3.2.1-rc3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:C:/PROGRA~2/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe
  "cmTryCompileExec2091697540/fast"

  C:/PROGRA~2/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe -f
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2091697540.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2091697540.dir/build


  make.exe[1]: Entering directory
  `C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/OpenSceneGraph-3.2.1-rc3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'



  "C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report
  C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/OpenSceneGraph-3.2.1-rc3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles
  1


  "Building C object
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2091697540.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj"


  "C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/bin/clang.exe" -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2091697540.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -c
  C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/OpenSceneGraph-3.2.1-rc3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c



  clang.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable

  clang.exe: error: assembler (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use
  -v to see invocation)

  make.exe[1]: ***
  [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2091697540.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Fehler 1


  make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
  `C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/OpenSceneGraph-3.2.1-rc3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'



  make.exe: *** [cmTryCompileExec2091697540/fast] Fehler 2






  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:47 (PROJECT)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/OpenSceneGraph-3.2.1-rc3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/OpenSceneGraph-3.2.1-rc3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

What can be the reason for this? Is there an incompatibility between the programs, or are there environment variables missing?

Answer (score 0):

Either your clang installation is broken/uncomplete or it could be a cmake [bug](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14863). First check that you are able to compile "hello world" directly with clang (without cmake)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to use the Visual Studio generator with the correct toolset for clang

http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14863

I don't know if cmake-gui has a way to set the toolset, so try on the command line instead.

```
cmake.exe .. -T LLVM-vs2010
```

Comment: I don't have the Visual Studio toolset installed nor do I intent to do so. Isn't there a way to make it work without yet another toolchain? The generator I use is `Eclipse CTD - Unix Makefiles` (with GnuWin32-make) or `Eclipse CTD - Ninja Makefiles`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your sdk direction doesn't have some special character such as: '(',')',' '.
check the log by .txt reader. the log is in the .externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/Tc10U2kUC8g), **clang** on Windows must be able to find **link.exe**.

I tested it with an old Visual Studio Express edition linker, and it worked just fine.